# Mongo shell adding extra line on export file

Tags: mongodb

I have wrote a mongo shell script (JS) for exporting some data in CSV format. I'm executing the script using the following command:

`mongo export.js > data.csv`

everything is wring to data.csv file but it's also adding the below line on top of the file

`MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:27017/admin
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3`

How I can avoid the above text getting added my CSV file?

Thanks,
Unnikrishnan B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/):

> `--quiet`
>
> Silences output from the shell during the connection process.

So ...

```
mongo --quiet export.js > data.csv
```